# Extending Enum in scalaz and implicit parameters with subtypes

Tags: scala, scalaz

I was playing with scalaz and thought I could extend `Enum` type class for something to make myself understand scalaz better. So I wrote this:

```
    sealed abstract trait Counter
    case object First extends Counter
    case object Second extends Counter
    case object Third extends Counter

    implicit val enumCounter: Enum[Counter] = new Enum[Counter] {
      override def succ(a: Counter): Counter = a match {
        case First => Second
        case Second => Third
        case Third => First
      }

      override def pred(a: Counter): Counter = a match {
        case First => Third
        case Second => First
        case Third => Second
      }

      override def order(x: Counter, y: Counter): Ordering = {
        val map = Map[Counter, Int](First -> 0, Second -> 1, Third -> 2)
        implicitly[Order[Int]].order(map(x), map(y))
      }
    }

    println(First |=> Third)
    println(First.succ)
```

But it turns out that it doesn't work as I hoped it will. `First` does not have `succ` nor `|=>`, because I've created `Enum[Counter]` but not `Enum[First]`. If I write `First.asInstanceOf[Counter].succ` it starts to resolve. Which is now obvious to me. But how can I implement `Enum` typeclass then in a simple way? I do not want to declare separate implicit values for each of `Enum[First]`, `Enum[Second]`....

There are two possible solutions I am thinking of:

1) Make scala resolve `Enum[First]` as `Enum[Counter]`. But I cannot seem to understand how this can be possible as `Enum` can be only nonvariant

2) Maybe there is a solution in scalaz?

Otherwise `Enum` typeclass starts to be quite limited, as it does not supports Enum which sounds very weird.

I am actually not sure how much this question belongs to `scalaz`, it probably depends on whether the solution is (1) or (2). If the solution is (1) - this question is pure scala.

Comment: Looks like you're basically doing what the scalaz example digit does:https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fscalaz%2FDigit.scala

Comment: To get around the issue you would do something like `(First: Counter)` from the examples similar usage https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/example%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fscalaz%2Fexample%2FEnumUsage.scala

Comment: @Noah Thanks for the response. Type ascription is something I wanted to avoid. But it appears that scalaz is designed so it is not possible to do the stuff I want. I've asked the same question second time - while rephrasing a lot, and I've got an answer, if you are interested - please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907387/typeclasses-and-inheritance-in-scalaz In short the solution is very alike type ascription, but the idea is to encapsulate it in methods, and this is how it is done in scalaz itself. Haskell does it much better, but it is impossible in scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rethought the question and rephrased it a lot - and received an answer, please see this: [Typeclasses and inheritance in scalaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907387/typeclasses-and-inheritance-in-scalaz)